# How to disable a sub-form in ms access form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I had this project where I have to make a program with a login and different levels of access according to which user loged in. So i made the login form and after that i had this form where it have three sub-forms, each labeled level_1-3. The idea is if the user has access level 1 the two sub-forms will be disabled and the first form only will be enabled.

the code i used looks something like this

```
If Not rs.EOF Then
        Acesslevel = DLookup("[Access_level]", "managers_data", "username.Value")
        MsgBox " Welcome " & username.Value & ". Acess level " & Acesslevel & " Granted!!"
        DoCmd.Close
        If Acesslevel = 1 Then 
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Home"
            x
        If Acesslevel = 2 Then 
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Home"
            y
        If Acesslevel = 2 Then 
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Home"
            z
```

so my question is  what code should i insert in places of x so that the two sub-forms (sub-form level_2 and level_3 are disabled and level_1 is enabled) and the same question goes for y and z.  the name of the form is home. and i am using ms access 2013. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be:

```
<snip>
DoCmd.Close

DoCmd.OpenForm "Home"
Forms!Home!SubformControlX.Enabled = False
Forms!Home!SubformControlY.Enabled = False
Forms!Home!SubformControlZ.Enabled = False

Select Case Acesslevel
    Case 1 
        Forms!Home!SubformControlX.Enabled = True
    Case 2
        Forms!Home!SubformControlY.Enabled = True
    Case 3 
        Forms!Home!SubformControlZ.Enabled = True
End Select
```

Comment: Thank you but what does SubformControl indicate.

Comment: Thank you so much I got what the subform controle indicate, it is the name of the navigation button.

Comment: How to add a another case when there is a different value for te Acesslevel. is it also possible to make the subforms invisible.

Comment: You can expand and modify the Select-Case as you like. To hide the subform, set the property _Visible_ to False.